# Why is this a syntax error?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash function as follows:

```
function folderSize{
    du -hs | awk '{print $1}'
}
folderSize
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
./size.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `du' ./size.sh:

line 2: `   du -hs | awk "{print $1}"'
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: a few problems. 1. you do not need $ in invoking function. 2. you need an argument for du command 3. when you call a bash function, you do not use parens, just whatever string you need for the arg. my version works and you can inspect it more carefully.

Comment: shouldn't du -hs run on the cwd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

space is required before the {.

```
function folderSize {
  du -hs | awk '{print $1}'
}
```

Also, the way you call the function is just `folderSize`, no dollar sign, no parentheses.

Comment: i have changed it to `function folderSize{ du -hs | awk '{print $1}' }` still have the same error

Comment: looks like you still have no space.  You need a space after 'folderSize' and before '{'.  And if you're going to try to declare it all on one line, you also need a semicolon before the '}'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if syntax of your variant is correct. I usually do it somewhat like this:

```
folderSize() {
  du -hs | awk '{print $1}'
}
folderSize
```

Comment: fnName() is the old Bourne shell syntax, and it works fine.  Since parentheses break up the parsing, you can get away without the space, too: `folderSize(){ du -hs | awk '{print $1}'; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
function folderSize {
    du -hs $1 | awk '{print $1}'
}

folderSize '.'
```

Comment: Don't know why you introduced a parameter, or why you're quoting the argument in the call, but that would be better done as `du -hs "$@"` for maximum generality.

Comment: Thanks, yes. You are right about the argument generalization. I was just trying to make it work :-) I added an argument just to test the current directory.